# rails filter boolean attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filtering

I need to add filter to my search form. I need my search can filter the place that has either 'toy' or 'high chair'. I'm little bit confuse how to create if else condition in controller if the user add one of the filter, both or none.

```
Places
t.string "name"
t.string "address"
t.float "latitude"
t.float "longitude"
t.bigint "user_id"
t.boolean "toy", default: false
t.boolean "high_chair", default: false

// Controller
def index
 @places = policy_scope(Place)
 @text_search = params[:search]

 if @text_search.present?
  @places = Place.global_search(params[:search]).where(type: @types).where(toy: 
  params[:toy].where(high_chair: params[high_chair])
 else
  @places = Place.all
  @result = "No Result"
 end
end

// View
<%= form_tag(places_path, method: :get, class: "search-form") do %>
 <div class="search-input">
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search],
                     class: "search-input form-control",
                     placeholder: "Type your city...'"%>
  <%#= check_box_tag(:toy) %>
  <%#= label_tag(:toy, "Toys") %>
  <%#= check_box_tag(:high_chair) %>
  <%#= label_tag(:high_chair, "High Chair") %>
  <%= submit_tag "", class: "search-submit btn-search"  %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) gem, it would be easier.

```
// View
<%= search_form_for @query, url: places_path, method: :get, class: "search-form" do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :high_chair_true %>
  <%= f.check_box :high_chair_true %>
  <%= f.label :high_chair_false %>
  <%= f.check_box :high_chair_false %>
  <%= f.label :toy_true %>
  <%= f.check_box :toy_true %>
  ...
  <%= f.submit "search" %>
<% end %>

// Controller
def index
  @query = Place.ransack(params[:query])
  @places = @query.result
end
```

play with the combinations to fit your needs.

Comment: Hi Fernand, Thanks for your recommendation. Unfortunately, ransack doesn't give a result that i want.